# Why does TensorFlow create extra name spaces for my variables in the TensorBoard visualization?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I create variables as follows:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, D], name='x-input') # M x D
# Variables Layer1
#std = 1.5*np.pi
std = 0.1
W1 = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([D,D1], mean=0.0, stddev=std, name='W1') ) # (D x D1)
S1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(100.0, shape=[1], name='S1')) # (1 x 1)
C1 = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([D1,1], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1, name='C1') ) # (D1 x 1)
```

but for some reason tensorflow adds extra variable blocks in my visualization:

[image]

Why is it doing this and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly using names in TF

```
W1 = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([D,D1], mean=0.0, stddev=std, name='W1') )
                  \----------------------------------------------------------/
                                           initializer 
     \-------------------------------------------------------------------------/
                                 actual variable
```

Thus your code creates **unnamed variable**, and **names initializer op** `W1`. This is why what you see in the graph named `W1` is not your `W1` but rather **renamed initializer**, and what should be your `W1` is called `Variable` (as this is the default name TF assigns to unnamed ops). It should be

```
W1 = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([D,D1], mean=0.0, stddev=std), name='W1' )
```

Which will create node named `W1` for actual variable, and it will have a small initialization node attached (which is used to seed it random values).